# Redirecting a folder from the view of a program in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-8.1, folder-redirection

I've noticed a lot of programs like to store data in my documents under windows. A lot of games will create folders in my documents. I like to keep my documents synced over skydrive and I was wondering if I could somehow redirect these folders elsewhere and then hide the redirect. Basically, I don't want game data saved to skydrive. Its a waste of space.

I want to either redirect certain folders from skydrive/documents to other folders in my file system

OR

change where the applications store files (keep all of the files in "Program Files" or a new folder "Program Data")

[image: screenshot of what I want]

That's how I have my documents setup. I don't mind manually redirecting each program's data folder within skydrive/documents to lets say... "C:\Program Data\PROGRAMNAMEGOESHERE"

Comment: Its not clear what you want.  In one sentence you say you like to sync your documents in another you don't want to sync them.  The problem you will face is that the Skydrive folder by default is now part of your user Profile.

Comment: @Rahmou Here's my interpretation: He wants to sync his documents folder with skydrive. Some programs (e.g. games) store data under his Documents folder as well. He doesn't want those synced. Is that correct?

Comment: @zdan thats correct! sorry for confusion!